# Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application when trying to call wind32 dll from ASP.NET on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, winapi, iis-7

I'm trying to load win32 dll in ASP.NET application on IIS 7, OS Windows Server 2008R2, but it  throws "%1 is not a valid Win32 application". 
The application is loading the dll and works properly on my dev machine and Visual Studio 2012 development server, Winodws 8 64bit.

When I set "Enable 32-Bit Applications"=true on the application pool error is not thrown but nothing happens, the application is not responding and timeout is exceeded.

Any ideas of how to get win32 dll working ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to run the worker process as Wow64(32-bit)?

In that case there is a good chance that your configuration is trying to load some 64-bit isapi filter, for example aspnet_filter.dll,for v2.0, on a 64-bit OS there will be two instances of this dll on your machine under \framework and \framework64 folders. You want to select the one under \framework.

Comment: Hi 
- when "Enable 32-bit applications"=false the application is working properly and it serves requests until I try to load the win32 dll - error "%1 is not a valid Win32 application" is thrown.

- When I "Enable 32-bit applications"=true, the application is still working but when I try to load the application nothing happens and timeout is exceeded. I have logging enabled before and after the code where dll should be load and I can see that it is not loaded. Nothing happens in that case.